# recover files due to mistakes with git

Tags: git

I made the following steps:

- I had some files F1, F2, F3, ... in a folder `F` initialized with `git clone` from a remote empty repository
- I executed `git add .`

Then I made two mistakes:

- first, I ran in `F`: `git reset --hard HEAD`
- second, I removed the `.git` folder in `F`

Now the directory `F` is empty and I have lost all my files.
Is there any way to recover the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to recover the files?

No.

This was an interesting perfect storm of errors. Saying

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

is very violent; it means, restore everything in the working tree to be exactly the same as the most recent commit. All uncommitted changes are thus erased.

Fortunately, however, a hard reset does not touch *untracked* files. So the new files you created should still be there, right?

Wrong, because you first said

```
git add .
```

This turned your new untracked files into *tracked* files! So the hard reset erased them completely.

The files were never committed so they were lost completely. But even if they *had* been committed, you would then have thrown that commit away when you deleted the *.git* folder!

So basically you erased your files without backing them up first, and then, just in case you *had* backed them up, you threw away the backup.

Comment: Thank you. I already knew the answer, but hope is the last thing to die.